# contenteditable - add a class to a current div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

`currentDiv` is the div having the caret inside
on a button click I need to add a class
problem - how to get which div is the current ?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
$(currentDiv).addClass('indent');
});
```

```css
.indent{margin-left:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>ipsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and the `startContainer` property to get the element pointed to by the cursor:

```js
const contenteditable = $('[contenteditable]');
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var elem = range.startContainer.parentNode;
  $(elem).addClass('indent');
});
```

```css
.indent {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>
  <div>lorem</div>
  <div>ipsum</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```